# what does it mean for the transpose of a matrix to be the negative of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, transpose

Say I have matrix A,if $A^{T} = A$ then A is symmetrical. But what does it mean if $A^{T} = -A$ and can I know something about such a matrix inverse?

Comment: Doesn't it mean that all of the diagonal entries must be zero? Can such a matrix be invertible?

Comment: yes it can be invertible

Comment: This can be a skew-symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 5):

$A^T+A=0$ implies that $-a_{i,j}=a_{j,i}$ for all $i,j$, and in particular, $a_{i,i}=0$ for all $i$.

$\det(A)=\det(A^T)=\det(-A)=(-1)^n\det(A)$, so if $n$ is odd the determinant is 0, i.e. $A$ is non-invertible.

Comment: Good job. It can also be shown that a skew symmetric matrix always has an even rank. Fits perfectly together with your point.

Comment: It is also notable that the inverse of $A$ (should such an inverse exist) has the same property. That is, $$[A^{-1}]^T=-A^{-1}$$

Comment: Pedantic remark: That's if the characteristic is different from $2$. In characteristic $2$, a skew-symmetric matrix is symmetric, and can be nonsingular also in odd dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the matrix is over the reals the following item springs to mind. If $A^T=-A$, then consider the set of matrices
$$
G=\{\exp(tA)\mid t\in\Bbb{R}\}.
$$
Here $\exp$ is the usual exponential function defined as a (everywhere convergent) power series
$$
\exp(X)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{X^k}{k!}.
$$
Whenever two matrices $X,Y$ commute, i.e. $XY=YX$, then we have 
$$
\exp(X+Y)=\exp(X)\exp(Y).
$$
Compare with the usual result $e^{x+y}=e^x\cdot e^y$.

In particular this means that $\exp(tA)\exp(-tA)=\exp(0)=I$, so $\exp(tA)^{-1}=\exp(-tA)$. Here (finally!) we get to use the fact $-A=A^T$. Together with the preceding point we see that
$$
\exp(tA)^{-1}=\exp(t(-A))=\exp(tA^T)=\exp(tA)^T.
$$
In other words all the matrices in the set $G$ are orthogonal - their inverse is equal to the transpose.

TL;DR; The set $G$ is a group of orthogonal matrices.

Comment: Sorry. I used to know a few things about Lie algebras, and couldn't resist. The matrix $A$ would be called *an infinitesimal generator* of $G$. The name is justified as follows. If $\epsilon$ is a small real number then the first order approximation is
$$\exp(\epsilon A)=I+\epsilon A.$$ The remaining terms have $\epsilon^2$ or higher.