# Basis of $SO(4)$ group

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebras

I have a rotation matrix

$$ R_{(\phi)} = \left( 
\begin{matrix}
\cos (\phi) & \sin (\phi) & 0 & 0 \\
-\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi) & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right).
$$

Now I needed to show that this rotation is in $SO(4)$. I showed that $\det R_{(\phi)} = 1$. Is that enough or are there more things that need to be shown here? Further I should compute the generator in this matrix (at $\phi=0$):

$$L = \frac{d}{d \phi} R_{(\phi)} = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right)
.$$
Now I need to find the basis of $SO(4)$, it's dimension and describe it in form of matrices. I have no idea how to do that. Does someone have a hint?

Comment: In order to find a basis for (the Llie algebra of) $SO(4)$ you need to have a definition of $SO(4)$. What's yours?

Comment: I am not sure if I can answer this questions but as far as I understood it should be 4x4 orthogonal matrices with real entries and a determinant equal to 1. Does that help?

Comment: That would be my definition, too. In that case the Lie algebra consists exactly of real antisymmetric matrices. See [my recent answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1511476/11619). Can you find a basis for the space of antisymmetric 4x4 matrices?

Comment: You also need to show that $R^TR=I$